# Protractor set div innerHTML or manipulate DOM

Tags: angular, protractor, quill

Using Protractor for Angular, need to update a DIV's inner HTML.

The following is not reflecting the change:

```
element(by.className("ql-editor")).sendKeys("new content");
```

The reason for this is to test an Angular page that includes an HTML editor (Quill). The value of the editor is displayed in the browser as the inner HTML of a DIV with class ql-editor.

What is the best way to achieve this? (can´t find any function to update values beyond sendKeys)

Is it possible to work with native DOM objects in Protractor or to convert an ElementFinder object to a javascript DOM object?

Comment: you can run a custom script which manipulates an DOM Object and its properties:https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typescript function updates the innerHTML property of an element located with Protactor:

```
setHTMLValue(element: ElementFinder, value: string) {
    function setInnerHTML (div, content) {
        div.innerHTML = content;
    }
    browser.executeScript(setInnerHTML, element, value);
}
```

Example of use:

```
let element = element(by.id("d0"));
setHTMLValue(element, "test");
```